# How to run `args` as `command` in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I have a python script I want to run in a kubernetes job. I have used a `configMap` to upload it to the container located for example in `dir/script.py`.

The container is run normally with the `args["load"]`.

I have tried using a postStart lifecycle in the `Job` manifest but it appears not to run.

```
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c 
              - /usr/bin/python /opt/config-init/db/tls_generator.py
```

Below is the snippet of the manifest

```
      containers:
      - name: {{ template "gluu.name" . }}-load
        image: gluufederation/config-init:4.0.0_dev
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c 
              - /usr/bin/python /opt/config-init/db/tls_generator.py
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /opt/config-init/db/
            name: {{ template "gluu.name" . }}-config
          - mountPath: /opt/config-init/db/generate.json
            name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-mount-gen-file
            subPath: generate.json
          - mountPath: /opt/config-init/db/tls_generator.py
            name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-tls-script
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: {{ template "gluu.fullname" . }}-config-cm
        args: [ "load" ]
```

How can I run the `tls_generator.py` scipt after the `args["load"]`.

The dockerFile part looks like

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--", "/app/scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Container Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/), to be more specific `PreStop`.

> This hook is called immediately before a container is terminated due to an API request or management event such as liveness probe failure, preemption, resource contention and others.

If you want to execute a command when `pod` is starting you should consider using `PostStart`.

> This hook executes immediately after a container is created. However, there is no guarantee that the hook will execute before the container ENTRYPOINT. No parameters are passed to the handler.

Another option would be using [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers), and here are few ideas with examples:

> - Wait for a  [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)  to be created, using a shell one-line command like:
>
> ```
>  for i in {1..100}; do sleep 1; if dig myservice; then exit 0; fi; done; exit 1
> ```
>
> - Register this Pod with a remote server from the downward API with a command like:
>
> ```
> curl -X POST http://$MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_HOST:$MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_PORT/register -d >'instance=$(<POD_NAME>)&ip=$(<POD_IP>)'
> ```
>
> - Wait for some time before starting the app container with a command like
>
> ```
> sleep 60
> ```

Please read the documentation on how to use [Init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

My end goal was to run `tls_generator.py` right after the load command has completed. This is what I came with and is working fine.

```
  command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  args: ["tini -g -- /app/scripts/entrypoint.sh load && /usr/bin/python 
              /scripts/tls_generator.py"]
```

In this case the default command when running `"tini -g -- /app/scripts/entrypoint.sh"` will be the `--help` command. But adding `load` passes it as a command.